# Object instantiated with null values before end of callback retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-boot, retrofit2

I'm performing 3 callbacks in order to retrieve 2 objects : `Student` and `Course` and insert 1 object : `absence` from and in my database. 
I need the objects `Student` and `Course` in order to instantiate my object `Absence` but the problem is that it gets instantiated with null values that correspond to `Student` and `Course` objects respectively. The problem is that the object is instantiated before the end of the callbacks that retrieve the two other objects.
I'm using Retrofit to send Http Request.
I'm using Spring boot and Hibernate in server side.

Here is the code :

```
Call<Student> studentCall = client.getStudentById(id);
        studentCall.enqueue(new Callback<Student>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Student> call, Response<Student> response) {
                student = response.body();
                Log.i("STUDENT :", student.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Student> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("FAIL STUDENT :", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

Call<Course> courseCall = client.getCourse(c);
        courseCall.enqueue(new Callback<Course>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Course> call, Response<Course> response) {
                course = response.body();
                Log.i("COURSE : ", course.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Course> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("FAIL COURSE ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

Absence absence = new Absence();
        absence.setCourse(course);
        absence.setCourse_session(session);
        absence.setStudent(student);
        Log.i("ABSENCE  :" , absence.toString());
        Call<Absence> absenceCall = client.addAbsence(absence);
        absenceCall.enqueue(new Callback<Absence>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Absence> call, Response<Absence> response) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Absence> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Any recommendations ?

Comment: *I'm performing 3 callbacks in order to retrieve 2 objects* that is bad on the start :)

Comment: @Antoniossss Ok thank you what would be the solution ?

Comment: It would be a better solution to create an endpoint for absence, where you pass the id's for course and student, and handle the logic server side. Then on the client you will only need to make one call to this endpoint.

Comment: I have tried to do this but I cannot pass too many @Body argument

Comment: In retrofit the error says : too many @Body arguments